# Keystroke to be written to file

Tags: php, javascript, keyboard

I am using JS onkeyup and onkeydown function to check the key pressed by the user. I want this information to be passed to a file in server. I tried inserting php file commands inbetween js but that dint work out. All my key related functions are in js.

For example, if a user presses W, i want the web program to write W/ to the file in the server.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Good idea. Server-side keylogger. :)

Comment: > http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ needs to be called when `onkeyup` is fired. In the PHP file you then simply need to `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, `fclose()` - look @ php.net for these functions.

Comment: Thank you, I m going to try that a little worried about the buffer. Bcoz i m expecting a fairly immediate and fast interface between the client and the remote application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send the keystroke data from javascript to a PHP script in your server (where you'll log them in a file) using, in example, an Ajax call. The [jquery](http://jquery.com) library can help you in this task. Look at these tutorials on using [ajax](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/) [calls](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/ajax-jquery) [from](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development.html) jquery.

I would suggest you to buffer the keystroke data on the client and send batch of information to your PHP server script, to improve the performances of the system

Comment: I dont how it will work out for my project. I am trying to send user data to move a Arduino-bot(like thats not been done b4). So what i am doing is sending the user keystroke to the server file. this file will be read by a python script and will be sent to the bot using serial communication. The user can control the bot usind W,A,S,D.

Comment: if this is your need, then avoid the buffering of course. The rest of the answer is still valid for your scenario. The PHP script can create the file. BTW you can send serial data directly from PHP using the dio_* functions. Check this page:http://php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php

Comment: Just to improve it i was thinking if the client can directly contact the pc to which the bot is synced and the pc can create a buffer, constantly sending he data serially to  the bot.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) technology in order to do this.
I suggest you to check the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) javascript library that has simple Ajax methods.
The PHP file will look something like this :

```
//receive.php 
$key = $_POST["key"]; // sending with POST method
file_put_contents("keylogger.txt",$key,FILE_APPEND);
```